# Calculus 2 - cross section

Tags: calculus

The base of a certain solid is the triangle with vertices at (−4,2), (2,2), and the origin. Cross-sections perpendicular to the y-axis are squares. What is the volume of the solid.

I am really confused on how to do this question i have gotten 12 but the answer is wrong
this what i did

$$\int_{-4}^2 2 \,dx=12$$

[image]

Comment: I have edited with a suggestion, quite apart from your question. After pondering on it improve it and / or delete it.

Answer (score 2):

The right side of the triangle is a line with equation $y=x, x\in[0,2]$. The left, $y = -\frac{1}{2}x, x\in [-4,0]$. The top is simply $y = 2$.

As you can see from the picture: [image: graph]the side length of the square due to taking a cross section has length $x_1-x_2 = y - (-2y) = 3y$. So for a given $y$ the square has area $9y^2$. Therefore the integral we need to evaluate is $$\int_0^29y^2\text{d}y$$ and I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: Thanks this really helped a lot i was able to other questions on my own